# How to start a Blazor app from a static HTML file?

Tags: c#, blazor

I would like to have a static homepage that launches into a Blazor app. How do you set up the routing so that I have a normal Razor page as a home page (index) and change the default start url for the blazor app?

I tired playing around with the routing, but it either launches into the blazor app or crushes.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: Server or Web Assembly?  This article shows how to build a Blazor site from a DotNet razor site which may well give you enough information to resolve your problem - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web